# Is there any way to hide pairing message box during miracast device using 'RequestStartCasting'?

Tags: c#, uwp, miracast

1. Connected Miracast device in display monitor
2. Create connection with Miracast device using 'CastingDevice.CreateCastingConnection()'
3. Casting request with  with Miracast device 
   using 'castDeviceConnection.RequestStartCastingAsync()'

**Device paring message box showing after 'RequestStartCastingAsync()' call.
Is there any way to hide these message box??**

sample code:

```
            //Create a new casting connection to the device that's been selected
             castDeviceConnection = SelectedCastingDevice.CreateCastingConnection();

            //Register for events
            castDeviceConnection.ErrorOccurred += Connection_ErrorOccurred;
            castDeviceConnection.StateChanged  += Connection_StateChanged;

            //casting test image
            Image castImage = new Image();
            castImage.Source = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage
                                                        (new Uri(@"ms-appx:////Assets/test.jpg"));
            CastingConnectionErrorStatus status = CastingConnectionErrorStatus.Unknown;

            // Request for casting
            castDeviceConnection.RequestStartCastingAsync( castImage.GetAsCastingSource());
```

Comment: It's by design. Did you have any special operations? Why did you want to hide the paring message box?

Comment: Sometimes API connect properly with miracast device. Sometimes not. API shows these kind of inconsistency. So im checking there is any difference, if the pairing messagebox is hidden.

Comment: I do not think you can hide the pairing message box.